# Behavior of static variables in objects of derived classes

Tags: c++, static

If I have a static variable in my base class, for example type of integer. Will I also have the same copy of that variable for the objects of derived classes?

Also, can the keyword static be used with strings?

Comment: The answer to both questions is yes.

Comment: Why would you think the type of the static variable makes a difference?